# Does this make sense to try to save memory?

Tags: java

```
public class KGEntry {

    private String sku;
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private String brand;

    public static final class KGEntryKey {
        private String sku;
        private String question;

        public KGEntryKey(String sku, String question) {
            this.sku = sku;
            this.question = question;
        }

       // hash and equals
    }
}
```

Now I want to create:

```
 Map<KGEntryKey, KGEntry> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Since the 'sku' & 'question' are the same in both KGEntry and KGEntryKey, does it reduce memory usage if I change the design to:

```
public class KGEntry {

        private String answer;
        private String brand;

        public static final class KGEntryKey {
            private String sku;
            private String question;

            public KGEntryKey(String sku, String question) {
                this.sku = sku;
                this.question = question;
            }

           // hash and equals
        }
    }
```

Now populate the map:

```
Map<KGEntryKey, KGEntry> map = new HashMap<>();
```

It doesn't seem to me to save memory. Is there a way to save memory usage in such a case?

Comment: `Map<KGEntryKey, KGEntry> map = new HashMap<>();` should not look like `Map<KGEntry.KGEntryKey, KGEntry> map = new HashMap<>();` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to save cents instead of carry out about dollars. Do not worry about your code. It works - this is fine. Memory performance is smth. more global and could not be done for given 10 lines of code. Do not worry, I am sure, I will not get any visible memory profit refactoring this code.

Comment: They are not references. Two copy of same strings are duplicated. Right? If the map is big, isn't the saving big? The reason I am looking for saving is because I got a GC outofmemory error.

Comment: Do not forget about string pool!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: All string literals are saved into string pool. And your same strings point to the shared or same string literal in memory.

Comment: I see. Thanks and make sense!

Answer (score 1):

The two classes KGEntryKey and KGEntry are unrelated to each other in any way, except that the definition of one is within the other. Their memory consumption has no effect on each other.

If you had a *reference* of one to the other, for example an instance field in KGEntry of type KGEntryKey, *or* if KGEntryKey was not `static` (in which case KGEntryKey instances would have a reference to their containing KGEntry instances), then you question may make more sense.

Comment: In my case, the two "sku" & "question" in KGEntry and KGEntryKey are exactly the same and are repeated. And that's why I suspect there is a way to avoid the duplication, especially if you the 'map' into consideration. I only key the 'sku' & 'question' in the Key of the map,  and thus remove the duplication. I can still access the two fields by call the method getKey and getQuestion from the KGEntryKey class.

Comment: @user697911 Those are just two **references** being duplicated. Assuming a reference costs 4 bytes, since you have 2 of them, if your map has a million entries, it would save 8 MB not to have them.

Comment: They are not references. Two Strings are saved. Right? If the map is big, isn't the saving big?

Comment: Unless you are obtaining/creating new strings for each usage, only one string is saved and there will be two references (like a pointer).